# Managing page specific Javascript: 1 big file with conditionals or multiple files

Tags: javascript, loading

In my project I have a load of functions that are used on every page, so I have put these in a single javascript file `common.js` and have included it in my footer template. My questions is, what is the best way to handle page-specific javscript?

For example, on one of my pages I have a google map. If my map js code is run on a page where I don't have an element with id map_canvas, I get an error.

Method 1: I could write some PHP which echos an additional script tag requesting `map.js` if and only if I'm on a map page.

Method 2: I could give the `<body>` of my map page an id of "map_page", then I could write a conditional clause in `common.js` along the lines of:

```
if (#map_page exists){
    put contents of map.js here
}
```

The problem with method 1 is that it increases the number of requests to the server.
The problem with method 2 is that it bloats my common javascript file.

Please can somebody explain, which, if any would be the preferred method to do this, or if neither are suitable, what I should do instead?

I have approximately 10 page-specific javascript files to deal with.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say that simpler is better. On every page, just add a script tag calling map.js. Or, in your common.js, you don't need to paste all of map.js's code. You can just create a new script tag with the js and call map.js like that. I would not recommend the php method. The easiest and simplest, therefore the least likely to be buggy method, is just to add another script tag to the pages that need it. Or if that is not an option, common.js could include this:

```
if(need map.js){
    var mapjs=document.createElement("script");
    mapjs.type="text/javascript";
    mapjs.src="map.js";
    document.body.appendChild(mapjs);
}
```